# Derbyjs v0.6 app.fn() doesn't exist

Tags: derbyjs

I'm following the Multi-Payer Notepad game tutorial on youtube and can't get the x-bind to work, because I get the following error:

```
app.fn('startGame', function(e, el) {
    ^
TypeError: Object #<App> has no method 'fn'
```

I'm assuming this method was changed in v0.6, since it just came out. Does anyone know the new way to complete this binding? This is what app.fn is doing:

```
app.fn('startGame', function(e, el) {
  var userId = model.get('_session.userId');
  this.model.set('_page.story.ready.' + userId, true);
});
```

Comment: you should post your solution as an answer and accept it instead of putting 'SOLVED' in the title.

Comment: The problem with that, is that I must wait two days. Yet I answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.component('story', Story);

function Story(){};

Story.prototype.startGame = function() {
  alert('clicked!');
  var userId = this.model.get('_session.userId');
  this.model.set('_page.story.ready.' + userId, true);
};
```

story.html

`<button type="button" on-click="startGame()">Click when you're ready</button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add the function to `app.proto`, like this:

```
app.proto.startGame = function (){
  alert('clicked!');
  var userId = this.model.get('_session.userId');
  this.model.set('_page.story.ready.' + userId, true);
};
```

This is based on how a helper function is added in the [TODO example](https://github.com/derbyjs/derby-examples/blob/master/todos/index.coffee#L93).